# mysql is enabled in php.ini but I'm still getting Call to undefined function mysql_connect()

Tags: php, mysql

We have a Windows 2008 server, this morning when we came to the office, we saw that mysql is not working

We are getting this error for a simple connect function

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()
```

but the strange thing is that mysql extensions are enabled in php.ini file.

```
extension=php_mysql.dll

extension=php_mysqli.dll

extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

According to `phpinfo()` , php using the ini file in `C:\PHP` and the DLL files exist in the ext folder.

I cannot find a way to solve or at least to find out what is causing this.

I would be grateful if someone could give me some advice

Thanks in advance

Comment: your using which server?linux or windows?and did you tried restarting xampp?

Comment: This should happen to each application using the mysql extension :D sorry for the offtopic

Comment: That's what you get for still using ext/mysql.  :)

Comment: @user2936213 - "Windows 2008 server" is a release of Windows.

Comment: Nevermind, this could also happen with PDO

Comment: Sorry at first i didn't read it.my mistake. :)

Comment: Try to restart Apache / IIS or reboot the whole server. In Apache a reload instead of a restart should work also.

Comment: we have even restarted the server but no changes...

Comment: If you run a php code called phpinfo() what you get as plugin installed?

Comment: Please post the relevant phpinfo() part, where "Mysql" is listed.

Comment: @MarcelBalzer well , there is only mysqlnd section but no mysql, my phpinfo() can be seen here http://jsfiddle.net/ZLtr8/1/

Comment: did you alter both c:\windows\php.ini and c:\php\php.ini

Comment: Is there an error listed in error.log of apache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for debugging purposes try

```
if ( !function_exists('mysql_connect') ) {
    echo '<pre>mysql extension loaded: ', extension_loaded('mysql') ? 'yes':'no', "\r\n";
    $cf = get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path');
    echo 'ini file: ', $cf, "\r\n";
    if ( !$cf || !file_exists($cf) ) {
        echo "no config file\r\n";
    }
    else {
        echo "mysql config options:\r\n";
        $mc = array_filter( file($cf), function($e) { return false!==stripos($e, 'mysql') && false!==stripos($e, 'extension'); });
        echo join("", $mc);
    }
    die('no function mysql_connect</pre>');
}
```

the output should be something like

```
<pre>mysql extension loaded: no
ini file: C:\Develop\php\php.ini
mysql config options:
;extension=php_mysql.dll
;extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
no function mysql_connect</pre>
```

which indicates that the line `extension=php_mysql.dll` has been commented out (in my php.ini).

In case this script shows that the php_mysql.dll indeed should have been loaded try to increase the log level of both php and your webserver and check the log file. Maybe windows couldn't load the dll because it depends on another dll which isn't present (in the correct version) anymore. E.g. the php_mysql.dll in "my" ext directory depends on MSVCR110.DLL which is present because I have Visual Studio installed, otherwise installing the Visual Studio 2012 redistributables would be required. Tools like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) can show you which dlls are required to run an application and/or dll.

Or it could be that the php_mysql.dll implements a different API version than your php core. E.g. if you have PHP 5.4 installed but the php_mysql.dll is for php 5.1 you will see an API magic key error in the log file.

Comment: thank you for your reply , I tried Dependency Walker. However it's great software , it didn't help to solve my issue , I'm thinking that there might be something wrong with my mysql configuration. I was wondering if you know a way to check mysql my.ini configuration

Comment: So you indeed found a sign in the error log that the dll could not be loaded?

Comment: yes, extension is not being loaded, only difference from your output is that all extensions you've listed are uncommented in mine, there is no section for mysql in phpinfo() and also I can use mysql from command line

Comment: And did you find some entry in the error log indicating that the webserver process (or the fcgi process) tried to load the dll but failed? (btw: which webserver do you use? And how is php execute, as cgi or as a webserver module?)

Comment: I couldn't find anything in apache logs and can't find a log for php , We're running apache+php+mysql, not wamp or xampp in windows server 2008 ,

Comment: When you start the httpd in a console (in the easiest case just open a cmd shell -as admin to be on the safe side- go to the httpd directory and type `bin\httpd.exe`) does something pop up in the console window (or maybe even a message box) related to a missing dll? Also try to request a "php page" while the httpd is running the console. When I rename some dll in the ext directory the error is logged as a _warning_ in the file pointed to by the `error_log` directive in the php.ini, looks like `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\php_pdo_mysql.dll'`

Comment: oh btw: Did it work for some time and then suddendly at some point stopped working? Your question certainly reads that way, so the question is: what did change over the weekend....

Comment: oh my.. thank you very much , I did get an error while runninh httpd manually, there was an miswriting in the php ini file. I fixed it and it works fine now , thanks a lot again you saved my day

Comment: I have the same error while using an official PHP 5.6.23 docker container that provides Apache. Using the method provided `php.in` has all the same extensions uncommented (mysql, mysqli, and pdo_mysql), but it says mysql is not loaded.  I can't tell from this answer what solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Restart Your WAMP Or XAMPP Server. You can check with Contral Panel of XAMPP Or WAMP

Comment: And if not using xampp or wamp, what?

Comment: sorry not using wamp or xampp

Comment: @Onur i Mean here Apache Server

Comment: @user2223410 again, if not using APACHE - then what?

Comment: @RoyalBg Some user use LAMP, Windows user mostly use WAMP or XAMPP so i said restart XAMMP or WAMP. There are many Server Apacha/IIS etc

Comment: @user2223410 I know what did you say, but your answer is not helpful yet. That's why I'm trying to get the words from you to make a complete answer. When the OP does not explicitly said that he is using a single software (server) then DO NOT reply with answer specific to this software.

Comment: @RoyalBg i am agree with u but i am newbee on SO so i dont know the standard for answer.

Comment: Just edit your answer and make it to fit a general problem :)

Comment: @djay it won't be a relevant edit :) I would not edit, if it make a completely different sense