# Docker PHP 5.6.23 with Apache and MySQL mysqli_connect is not a function with extension added

Tags: php, mysql, apache, docker

The docker environment serves files, but I can't make the database connection using `mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbName)` without getting an error that `mysqli_connect is not a function`.

Checked that `php.ini` is loaded properly using `phpinfo()` and accessing the container `docker exec -it server bash` and visually inspecting the file.  Searched online for related issues with this PHP version and Apache and found this [issue](https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/62#issuecomment-70306737), but it doesn't solve the problem though I've added the changes to the dockerfile.

Can anyone figure out why the `mysql` extension is not loading? The docker-compose file is complete and the dockerfiles are minimal outside of copying over `php.ini` so the containers can all be built from the code below with the replacement of env variables.

**Docker-Compose File**

```
version: '2'
services:
  server:
    container_name: server
    build:
      context: .docker/server
      dockerfile: apache-php.dockerfile
    image: ${APP_DOMAIN}/server
    ports:
     - "${APP_PORT}:80"
    volumes:
     - ${APP_SRC_PATH}:/var/www/html
    networks:
     - wv-net
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql:5.7.20
    ports:
     - "${DB_PORT}:3306"
    env_file:
     - .docker/database/env/mysql.env
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
     - wvsqldata:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    networks:
     - wv-net
networks:
  wv-net:
    driver: "bridge"
volumes:
  wvsqldata:
    driver: "local"
```

**php.ini**

The php.ini file that is copied over to the container where I've uncommented all the `mysql` extensions to be thorough:

```
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

**PHP-Apache Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:5.6.32-apache-jessie

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y nano \
  && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mysql mysqli

EXPOSE 80

COPY config/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
```

**MySQL Dockerfile**

```
FROM mysql:5.7.20

EXPOSE 3306
```

**index.php**

Used this [script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21088102/1148107) to check the `php.ini` and see if the `mysql` module is loading. It shows the extensions are uncommented, but the `mysql` extension is not loading.

```
<?php 

if ( !function_exists('mysql_connect') ) {
  echo '<pre>mysql extension loaded: ', extension_loaded('mysql') ? 'yes':'no', "\r\n";
  $cf = get_cfg_var('cfg_file_path');
  echo 'ini file: ', $cf, "\r\n";
  if ( !$cf || !file_exists($cf) ) {
      echo "no config file\r\n";
  }
  else {
      echo "mysql config options:\r\n";
      $mc = array_filter( file($cf), function($e) { return false!==stripos($e, 'mysql') && false!==stripos($e, 'extension'); });
      echo join("", $mc);
  }
  die('no function mysql_connect</pre>');
}
```

Which outputs:

```
mysql extension loaded: no
ini file: /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
mysql config options:
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
; Records communication from all extensions using mysqlnd to the specified log
no function mysql_connect
```

Also tried the connection using `mysqli`, but that fails as well:

```
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', $username, $password, $dbName);

if (!$link) {
    echo "ERROR: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL . '<br>';
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL . '<br>';
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL . '<br>';
    exit;
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: Shouldnt `.dll` be `.so`? or no extension.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone you are on the right track since `.dll` is for windows, but using `.so` extensions doesn't solve the problem

Comment: This helped me out. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the issue.  I was using `localhost` as the DBHOST in the connection and not the docker container name of `db`:

```
$link = mysqli_connect('db', $username, $password, $dbName);

if (!$link) {
    echo "ERROR: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL . '<br>';
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL . '<br>';
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL . '<br>';
    exit;
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

mysqli_close($link);
```